# JavaFX WebView - Popping up Javascript context menu

Tags: java, javascript, tinymce, javafx-2

I am working on integrating a JavaScript based HTML Editor into JavaFX WebView. (TinyMCE)
One of the features of this editor is to popup a context menu when right mouse clicking.

However, when this is done within WebView, it pops up WebView's own context menu.

As of version 2.2, there is a method called `setContextMenuEnabled` that allows me to disable it.
But when I do so, nothing pops up at all.

How can I get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TinyMCE 5 the `editor.plugins.contextmenu._getMenu(editor).showMenu(x,y);` is no longer available. I update [Avrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8840/avrom) solution:

```
    webView = new WebView( );
    webView.setContextMenuEnabled( false );
    webView.addEventHandler( MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, this::onMouseClicked );
...
    private void onMouseClicked( MouseEvent event ) {
    WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine( );
    if( event.getButton( ) == MouseButton.SECONDARY ) {
        JSObject clientRect = ( JSObject )engine.executeScript( 
            "tinymce.activeEditor.getContentAreaContainer().getBoundingClientRect()" 
        );
        int x = ( Integer )clientRect.getMember( "left" );
        int y = ( Integer )clientRect.getMember( "top" );
        y = ( int )( event.getY( ) - y );
        x = ( int )( event.getX( ) - x );
        if( y >= 0 && x >= 0 ) {
            engine.executeScript( 
                "tinymce.activeEditor.fire('contextmenu', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window, buttons: 2, "
                        + "clientX: " + x + ", clientY: " + y + " }, true);" 
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution.
However, the right click did not always work correctly. (e.g. if you right clicked on an image, it wouldn't bring up the Image menu item) Making changes to how the event was initialized seems to work. I have put in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own plugin that handles right clicks and shows a small popup menu. 
Have alook in the sopurce code of the `contextmenu` plugin shipped with tinymce. You may use most of it's code for this  and only need to implement the menu points yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.

TinyMCE is able to popup the context menu using the following JavaScript:

```
editor.plugins.contextmenu._getMenu(editor).showMenu(x,y);
```

Where `editor` is the reference to the given TinyMCE editor (e.g. `tinymce.currentEditor`) and x,y are the coordinates relative to the content area.

A handler can then be added to the JavaFX WebView that listens for right mouse clicks and the javascript can then be executed from there.

```
view.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                {
                    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
                    {
                        JSObject jsObject = (JSObject) engine.executeScript(TINYMCE_EDITOR
                                + ".getContentAreaContainer().getBoundingClientRect()");
                        int x = (Integer) jsObject.getMember("left");
                        int y = (Integer) jsObject.getMember("top");
                        y = (int) (event.getY() - y);
                        x = (int) (event.getX() - x);
                        System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
                        if (y >= 0 && x >= 0)
                            engine.executeScript(TINYMCE_EDITOR + ".plugins.contextmenu._getMenu(" + TINYMCE_EDITOR
                                    + ").showMenu(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                    }
                }
            });
```

The rest of the code tries to figure out what the correct x,y coordinates are.